# How to connect to MySQL Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, nuget-package, mysql-connector

New to C# programming, I'd like to be able to access `MySQL` Databases.

I know `MySQL connector/NET` and `MySQL for Visual Studio` are required for C# development. 
Do I need to install them into my app? 
Is it possible I can just release the connector DLL with the program?

Update: 
Are both of them required for the end-user or just the connector? 
Is there anything else they would need?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is package the DLL with you program, it should already be in your output debug/release folder when you run your program.

Comment: Note: MySQL for Visual Studio don't work in VS2010E

Comment: As for the above note by @EnriqueSanMartín [Version 2.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-what-is-new-20.html) and [Version 1.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-what-is-new-12.html) _Support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 was removed_.

Comment: See here if you need to connect to MySQL over SSH rather than directly on port 3306 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806799/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-c-sharp-over-ssh

Answer (score 121):

Install [Oracle's `MySql.Data` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Data
{
    public class DBConnection
    {
        private DBConnection()
        {
        }

        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set;}

        private static DBConnection _instance = null;
        public static DBConnection Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new DBConnection();
           return _instance;
        }
    
        public bool IsConnect()
        {
            if (Connection == null)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
                    return false;
                string connstring = string.Format("Server={0}; database={1}; UID={2}; password={3}", Server, DatabaseName, UserName, Password);
                Connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                Connection.Open();
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    
        public void Close()
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }        
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var dbCon = DBConnection.Instance();
dbCon.Server = "YourServer";
dbCon.DatabaseName = "YourDatabase";
dbCon.UserName = "YourUsername";
dbCon.Password = "YourPassword";
if (dbCon.IsConnect())
{
    //suppose col0 and col1 are defined as VARCHAR in the DB
    string query = "SELECT col0,col1 FROM YourTable";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        string someStringFromColumnZero = reader.GetString(0);
        string someStringFromColumnOne = reader.GetString(1);
        Console.WriteLine(someStringFromColumnZero + "," + someStringFromColumnOne);
    }
    dbCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you might face internet connection problems and you would like to try until you connect this won't work. Delete `if (_instance == null)` line. Also make `bool result = false` by default because it might be not connected for internet connections problems and many other actually, not only because database name wouldn't be set. In that case `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
                    return false;` because it will just throw an exception otherwise and might even return true which wouldn't be correct. However, upvoted, thanks for the clean code.

Comment: Why do you have a "circular" reference with a private constructor ? (`new DBConnection();` and `private DBConnection()`)

Comment: You'd have to do `connection = null` on `DBConnection.Close()` since it is singleton and you may want to use it again

Comment: This is great to get started ! I've already expanded a little on `public bool IsConnect()`.
To reuse the connection, after the `if` statement:
`else if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) { connection.Open(); }`
In your application you can just do `dbCon.IsConnect()` again, after you've closed it after a previous query.
So don't do `connection = null;` in `DBConnection.Close()` as Roman suggested, otherwise reusing won't work.

Comment: Great answer, but how do I connect to a certain port. My network is that both the dev, test and live data is on the same server, but on different ports. How can I connect to just 1 port.

Comment: `Error CS0103 The name 'databaseName' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: "MySqlConnection Connection" property needs to be set to public to access.

Answer (score 58):

You can use Package Manager to add it as a package and it is the easiest way. You don't need anything else to work with a MySQL database.

Or you can run this command in Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data
```

[**NuGet MySql.Data**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mysql.Data/)

Comment: If you search it through "Manage NuGet Packages" window, keep in mind that package name is **case sensitive**. Maybe not such an obvious thing for someone coming from package managers with lowercase names.

Comment: Thanks, it is very small detail, so if anyone wants to check complete step by step procedure to connect with MySQL Check 
https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/mysql-connection-in-c-console-application-example/321

Answer (score 19):

You must to download MySQLConnection NET from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Then you need add `MySql.Data.DLL` to MSVisualStudio like this:

1. Open menu project
2. Add
3. Reference
4. Browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.12\Assemblies\v4.5.2`
5. Add MySql.Data.dll

If you want to know more visit: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rsu1E4cjMQ)

To use in the code you must import the library:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

An example with connectio to Mysql database (NO SSL MODE) by means of **Click event**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Deportes_WPF
{

public partial class Login : Window
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string user;
    private string password;
    private string port;
    private string connectionString;
    private string sslM;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        server = "server_name";
        database = "database_name";
        user = "user_id";
        password = "password";
        port = "3306";
        sslM = "none";

        connectionString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private void conexion()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("successful connection");

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + connectionString);
        }
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conexion();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I like the method name `conexion`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code below, I tried it and found:
Instead of writing `DBCon  = DBConnection.Instance();` you should put `DBConnection DBCon - new DBConnection();` (That worked for me)

and instead of `MySqlComman cmd = new MySqlComman(query, DBCon.GetConnection());` you should put `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DBCon.GetConnection());` (it's missing the d)

Answer (score 3):

Another library to consider is MySqlConnector, https://mysqlconnector.net/. Mysql.Data is under a GPL license, whereas MySqlConnector is MIT. They also show better performance benchmarks.

Answer (score -6):

```
 private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "connectcsharptomysql";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
        database + ";" + "U`enter code here`ID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

Comment: You have copied this from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL This is already the answer from "bout Hamed Shams"

Comment: I agree, @Elmue -