# Diffrence between using `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql.data

I am trying to connect to a `MariaDB` server using the `MySql.Data.dll`. I think it should work since `MariaDB` is a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

Found a helpful answer [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618283/5252007), however there is one thing that confuses me.

At the very top of his code he or she uses `using MySql.Data` and `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient`. Other tutorials I have found only mention the `using MySql.Data`.

I apologize if the question is silly, but I really want to understand why is he or she using both statements and not just `using MySql.Data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` are used so you can remove `MySql.Data` because both classes are part of the namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

You could als write `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand` and remove both using statements.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! It makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio you can also rightclick your code / `Organize Usings` / `Remove Unused Usings` if you're not sure if a namespace is   necessary