# Can't connect to database from visual studio c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, wamp

I want to connect to database from my c# windows forms application. I tried using

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) {
 conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; User Id=root; Password=; Initial Catalog=dbName";
 conn.Open();
}
```

and when I build my project I get an error that `server wasn't found or wasn't accessible`.

I tried connecting through data source configuration wizard, but also database can't be found.

I use `WAMP` server, and I can find my database through `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: what error occurred?

Comment: @SachithMW It's a runtime error and it says: `Unhandled exception has occured in your application ... ... A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class Tutorial1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            // Perform database operations
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

Check this links,hope this will be helped to you

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html
- http://net-informations.com/q/faq/mysql.html

you can install MySql.Data by ,open Package Manager Console **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console** then type `Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.9.9` in there

Comment: @SachitMW What should I include to use `MYSqlConnection` class?

Comment: I don't have that `mysql.data` library, only `System.Data` , trying to find to download it now.

Comment: @wdc just use nuget inside visual studio https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Comment: @Takarii Thank you, will try later.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a `MySqlConnection` to connect to a MySQL database, see answer here

[How to connect to MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database)