# Use Google Cloud API in c#

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-sql, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-client

I having been trying to query databases from Google Cloud SQL in c#. However, I can't get it working.

I followed the Google Reference pages https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/databases/get and tried to do a simple thing such as get the list of databases first.

and in my `.csproj` file, I have imported several apis.

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.SQLAdmin.v1beta4"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis"/>
     <PackageReference Include='Google.Cloud.Iam.V1' version="1.0.0-beta12" />
     <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.28.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Also, I referred to the Github repo and find examples using BigQuery, PubSub and so on but no Cloud SQL. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples

Can someone give some advice or point me to the right direction?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs you have imported are needed if you want to create or modify Cloud SQL instances from your code, however you don't need them to *query* an instance.

If your goal is to query an instance you have created with the cloud console or gcloud command, then you should connect to it like any other MySQL database. [Documentation for the MySQL Connector/Net is here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/), and there's also a [SO question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database).  You will also need to [authorize the IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) that you are connecting from.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction. It totally helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

David is right.  Here are some samples that show you how to connect to an SQL database from C#:

dotnet *core*
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-cloud-sql

dotnet *4.x*
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql