# Windows Form "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm in  C# language and still learning about Model View Control. Now I have project for my school to make a cashier application, but I have this error when I'm trying to connect mysql database.

The error is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'port'.

this is my codes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace AppKasir.KoneksiDB
{
    class KoneksiBarang
    {
        public static SqlConnection getKoneksiBarang()
        {
            string strCon = "SERVER = localhost; PORT = 3306; UID = root; PWD = ; Database = db_kasirmysql;";
            return new SqlConnection(strCon);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is at line:

```
return new SqlConnection(strCon);
```

Which the symbol `;` is underline red.

Comment: Can you remove subsring `PORT = 3306;`. Port number 3306 is default for mysql and there is no need to specify it. If you remove it - error Is there anyway?

Comment: @AntonGorbunov yea there is, the error now from  dataGridViewBarang.DataMember = "barangkasir"; - An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Child list for field barangkasir cannot be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` represents an open connection to a SQL Server database.

Try this if you want to access a MySQL database:
[How to connect to MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's helpful and can fix my problem, sorry for long reply