# I installed my MySql Connector/Net before I installed the .NET core 2.0 did I do this installation correctly?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I installed .NET Core 2.0 after installing the MySQL Conector/Net 6.10.6. The requirement of the MySQL Connector with the version I have is to have a .NET Core 2.0, I am not sure if there will be an issue if I installed the connector prior to the .NET Core 2.0.

Shown are the MySQL Connector/Net requirements:
[image: MySQL Connector/Net Requirements]

What versions I have:

- Visual Studio 2017
- MySQL Connector/Net 6.10.6

Also when opening a project in Visual Studio 2017, I have these appearing. Not sure if it is an error:

```
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration started for <Practice,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration started for <Practice,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2> using <NUnit 3x,NUnitElementsSource> on thread <13:JetPool (S) Regular thread #1>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration skipped for <Practice,NUnit 3x,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>: project not supported by provider
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration started for <Practice,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2> using <NUnit 2x,NUnitElementsSource> on thread <13:JetPool (S) Regular thread #1>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration skipped for <Practice,NUnit 2x,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>: project not supported by provider
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration started for <Practice,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2> using <xUnit.net,XunitTestElementsSource> on thread <13:JetPool (S) Regular thread #1>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration skipped for <Practice,xUnit.net,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>: project not supported by provider
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration by <NUnit 3x> completed for <Practice, .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration by <NUnit 2x> completed for <Practice, .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration by <xUnit.net> completed for <Practice, .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>
[3/8/2018 12:02:38 PM] Exploration completed for <Practice,.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2>
```

Also when I try typing

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

It is not recognized by Visual Studio 2017. What is the issue?

Also, it says on my regedit.exe that my .Net framework is only up to 4.0:
[image: .Net Framework Version]

However, after trying to install the .NET framework 4.5, it says I have a .NET framework version of same or higher than it:
[image: Installation Error]

MySQL Connector/Net Files:
[image: MySQL Connector/Net]

Comment: Do you want to use .NET or .NET core?

Comment: According to this post, I need .NET core for the version of connector/Net that I have and for the current version of visual studio I have which is 2017. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html). I have no idea what the exploration started/skipped lines meant and why it had .NET framework 4.5.2 mentioned in them.

Comment: Ok, I get that, but which one are you trying to use, because for the .NET framework connector you don't need to include anything, just use the nuget tool to install the library and you're done:
Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.10.6

Comment: I can use anything that works. I just started programming to be honest, I do not know if there's a difference yet. So i'll just install the nuget tool? Will the .Net core 2.0 installations affect anything?

Comment: I'll show a screenshot of what the MySQL connector/net installation folder gave me. I believe it has those libraries?

Comment: I do not think so, just create a new C# application, and on the top bar, go to "Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console", type in "Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.10.6", add "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;" and you should be good to go

Comment: Alright thank you for your help. Hope it works so I can start coding lol

Comment: Anytime, can you give me an upvote for this? :)
It's always a good thing for people to start coding. But if possible, try to start with the basics!

Comment: I have a little knowledge on C#, MySQL, WPF language. I am also more familiar with VBA, but I still have lots to learn regarding basics for sure. Sure thing thanks

Comment: I'm confused though. I installed the connector and then using NuGet. Will that have an impact?

Comment: It worked so I believe there's no problem at all. One last thing though, can I ask where to find good documentation on how to use these libraries?

Comment: Well, most of the time you just have to google when you cannot find what you need and if you cant find it at all, you can post a question here on StackOverflow. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL This site expains a lot on how to get started, just skip to "using the code". Here is another person who couldn't get started by himself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you been searching a lot actually found the links you posted as well. Just needed more specific guidance. Thanks again