# Visual Studio 2017 + Identity + MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, identity

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio 2017 with Identity, but I cannot use the SQL Server. I need to use the MySQL. How can I setup the VS 2017 to create connection and tables (Identity tables) to MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: I hate doing this, but you can literally search "your programming language" "mySQL" and see pages of great results.  Existing SO answers often being on top.  Here is one for C#:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database

Comment: Here is one for .net core.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/   --  you may also try this page on customizing your user store for identity:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1  -- it is noted that you can change the user store to be used with Identity, and there are specific MySQL libraries readily available.