# Connect to remote DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

So this is what I have:

- Wordpress website hosted on a shared server X with the usual DB for the Wordpress instalation and a second DB with a table containing costumers
- Asp.net MVC app hosted on server Y that I need to connect to the costumer table to get all the costumers

I have search in SO and I come up with this in for the controller on the MVC app:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString =
                 "Data Source=**ip-address-of-server-x**/costumers" +
                 "User Instance=true;" +
                 "User Id=**user**" +
                 "Password=**pass**" +
                 "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;";
            conn.Open();
```

I'm getting "Server not found". I am not sure I can access the DB this way or maybe the problem is in the format of the Data Source string.

Comment: If it is a MySql database then why do you use the classes for connecting to Sql Server?

Comment: @Steve Thanks! You have pointed me in the right direction. I just followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546882/8211585