# Connect to OpenShift (Redhat Paas) mysql instance

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, openshift, tunnel

I'm trying to connect my c# application with openshift database. But I get this exception on the `conn.Open()`

```
Eccezione =>  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

this is my method:

```
 public void connect()
    {
        string connStr = @"Server=test-lound.rhcloud.com;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=XXXX;Pwd=YYYY;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successfull !");

            conn.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Eccezione =>  " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
```

what I doing wrong? Is possible establish a connection with a openshift database through c# client application?

**Edit**:
I found this document [here](https://forums.openshift.com/connect-a-mysql-client-sqlyog-to-mysql-5-on-openshift) that describes an SSH tunnel requirement. Perhaps that is necessary.

Comment: you may need to do an SSH tunnel. I will tweak the tags for this question. Please read [this](https://forums.openshift.com/connect-a-mysql-client-sqlyog-to-mysql-5-on-openshift). I added the `ssh` and `tunnel` tags to question. good luck.

Comment: you can't help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I absolutely can but on my android now. Will be on my computer in 1 hr

Comment: Ok thank you. It's a very big problem for me and now I'm currently stuck on this problem.

Comment: alright back in action. taking a look now. please let us know which version of openshift you have (gears, free, bronze, origin, enterprise, container, cluster) etc

Comment: I've a free version of openshift

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I finally worked it end-to-end but it is Mysql Workbench via ssh tunnel. It is a requirement for openshift as it is a PaaS sitting on top of IaaS AWS (Amazon EC2). So for the developer it is no problem. For the end-user, without a ssh-rsa public keypair, it won't work, as I see it.

A few good links to capture along the way: A site for quick and easy 2048bit ssh-rsa [key gen](http://generator.my-addr.com/generate_ssh_public_rsa_key-private_rsa_key-ssh_pair_online_tool.php). A [doc](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html) for putty and puttygen. The [doc](https://forums.openshift.com/connecting-to-openshift-mysql-using-workbench) for tunnel setup (critical); look what **dgreen** wrote.

A solution is to either supply a keypair with the app, and tweak your C# accordingly for the tunnel, or to go with AWS EC2 IaaS and it is a snap. AWS has a [Free-tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for a year. I could set that up easily, as that is where I am most familiar. But I must say I do like Openshift and its PHP front end.

Comment: refer to the 2 answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806799/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-c-sharp-over-ssh) question.

Comment: I actually worked with Putty to read the content FTP. I got to work with sockets with Java but with C # it is still new to this language now I am seriously in trouble. I see what I can combine, thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: In the future, this application will be distributed desktop, I may have your help to make this code? If you are willing to help me in private and make a tutorial along to other Skype users are available: John Carter (Avatar yellow with a picture of breaking bad)

Comment: Sure. You can find my contact info off my profile page. I want to put a Screencast vid together on how to configure

Comment: I have been messing around with the http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ project / library. I will share some c# stuff once I bang out an example.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted you on gmail with Ferven account, let me updated.