# Is it possible to establish a connection to a PostgreSQL database with ssh tunneling with a F# type provider?

Tags: postgresql, ssh, f#, ssh-tunnel

I can't find documentation about it. The SQL type provider I'm using is [this one](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/).

This is my code so far trying to use Renci.SshNet

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Renci.SshNet
open System

let connectionInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("159.203.79.134", "root", "322M5m@Q9Exs")
connectionInfo.Timeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0)
let client = new SshClient(connectionInfo)
client.Connect();
let portFw = new ForwardedPortRemote(Convert.ToUInt32(22),"159.203.79.134",Convert.ToUInt32(5432))
client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld)
portFwld.Start()

let [<Literal>] connString = "Host=***;Port=22;Database=testdb;Username=postgres;Password=***;"
let [<Literal>] dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL
let [<Literal>] resPath = @"../packages/Npgsql.3.1.9/lib/net451/"
let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000
let [<Literal>] useOptTypes = true

type sql = SqlDataProvider<dbVendor,connString,"",resPath,indivAmount,useOptTypes>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
    printfn "%A" argv
    0
```

But this only hangs.

This is how I connect to it through PG Commander [image: connection]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've tried everything from here https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/ It seems that it has to do nothing with the connection string but that I need to create first a ssh client. I'm trying with Renci.SshNet but I don't know which would be the host and which the bound host... I'm lost. It's my first time doing this. I'm trying to implement this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33857223/1120410

Comment: Please describe everything you tried, along with results you got, in the question. Provide code samples, error messages. Without detailed information about your problem nobody can help you to solve it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks for your feedback! I edited my question with it in mind.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I further improved my question

Comment: if you take out the type provider, and just try to connect to your postgres database, via `psql`, does that work? Something like: `psql -h localhost -p portNum -U your-db-username database-name`. See:  [SSH tunnel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html).

Comment: @s952163 No, it returns
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "187.190.152.199", user "postgres", database "pruebaf", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "187.190.152.199", user "postgres", database "pruebaf", SSL off
And your suggestion is ignoring the fact that I need to connect through a ssh tunnel

Comment: I mean set up the SSH tunnel first, hence the link, then psql to it via the localhost. I think before you can use the type provider it's probably better to trouble-shoot your SSH to postgres connection first. If you can connect via psql, then check if you can connect with npgsql using ADO.NET over ssh, if that works, then try the type provider.

Comment: @s952163 My bad. Yes, I'm able to connect that way. First I establish the tunnel on my machine: ssh -L 63333:localhost:22 root@159.203.**.** Then I connect to the db: psql -h 159.203.**.** -p 5432 -U postgres pruebaf How would that look using Renci.SshNet? Which is the bound port and which is the port? Right now, Renci.SshNet is crapping, so I can't just try everything. What I've tried is what it is on the post. Is it a ForwardedPortLocal or a ForwardedPortLocal? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Renci.SshNet, my guess is that it would be actually `ForwardedPortLocal` as you say, also I wonder if you can actually forward 5432 as that's already being used by postgres, use some higher portnumber exactly as in your tunneling example.